# Define / Declare an Object at Runtime VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, object, runtime

I use Objects to store information. The Problem is, I dont know what information i have to store, while i am compiling my App. For example, a user creates the information color and stores red in it, I want to create an object like:

```
  Public Class Information_Object
    Public Property general As Integer
    Public Property date As DateTime
    Public Property color As String = "red"
End Class
```

Is there a way to define an object during runtime?

Comment: [New Operator (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/new-operator)

Comment: @Jimi that doesnt really help me

Comment: There's no such thing as "declaring an object". You declare a type, variable, property, etc. You create an object, which is an instance of a type. You assign that object to a variable or property.

Comment: It doesn't? I usually does, when you have to *create an object*. If it *doesn't help*, then explain what *a user creates the information color* means and how the user *stores red in it* (what is *information* and how a user *stores* something *in it*) how the `New` operator cannot help you *to create an object like* `Information_Object`. as, e.g. `dim infoObject as New Information_Object() With { .color = [User Input Value] }`

Comment: For basic needs, look at a `Dictionary`. For something more advanced, look at the `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: @Jimi, even if you use an anonymous type, you still have to write the code to define the properties it will have. It seems like the OP is talking about defining the properties themselves at run time, not just the values of those properties.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  Maybe, what the OP wants to do is not clear at all. *I use Objects to store information*? What *Objects*? There's a concrete class shown there, but this is not what it actually is? Is there a *mutable* user input where the User not just creates values but also properties of *something*? What is this *something*? How is it used? Or stored. Or serialized. Is it? Or it just lives and dies at run-time for some specific purpose? Is there a purpose? Which is it? I could go on... or close it. The Socratic method not always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare an object/class at runtime, but you could create a generic object and repurpose it at runtime. For instance you might declare an object containing a variety of variables including one that describes how the object should be consumed.

**This pre-supposes that you can define how you object would be comsumed after it has been loaded with values.**

So, something like this might help:

```
Public ENUM Consume_As
   Colour
   Number
   Datetime
... and so on. Anything you like
End Enum

Public Class My_Dynamic_Object
  '
  '... You will have to create your GET/SET lines
'
'This is what tells your sstem how to consume data held in this class
  Public _comsume_as AS Consume_As

'Here is where you can store your data
'This can be anything you like
'a colour, dataset, another custom class ...
  Public Class_Variable_1 AS Object

End Class
```

Now you can create a dictionary of My_Dynamic_Object containing as many entries as you like created at run-time.
Each My_Dynamic_Object can contain a reference to [ENUM Consume_AS] to determine how My_Dymanic_Object should be handled, and whatever you like in Class_Variable_1.

You will need to write the necessary code to hand off My_Dynamic_Object.Class_Variable_1 for processing as neccessary.

Clunky ?? perhaps, but it might meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary.

```
    Dim dObjects As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    dObjects.Add("First Object", New TextBox With {.Text = "Textbox"})
    dObjects.Add("Second Object", 34533)
    dObjects.Add("Color", New Color = Color.Red)
    dObjects.Add("Date", Now())
    dObjects.Add("Whatever string...", "whatever object you want...")


    For Each k As String In dObjects.Keys
        Debug.Print(dObjects(k).GetType.ToString)
    Next
```